# how to use d3.js to make a partial hexbin like this

Tags: svg, d3.js

I have made a hexbin svg as the picture shown [image]

now I want to design a hexbin with a inner layer inside [image], which moves like a clock, this hexbin inner layer can be controlled by D3.js.

for example, 
if the partial hexbin is in 90 degrees, then the shape will be like [image]

if the partial hexbin is in 360 degrees, then the shape will be like [image]

Now I have no clue how to draw this partial shape with certain degree

Comment: Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: I want to draw the partial hexbin in certain degrees, it looks like the pie chart in the hexbin

Comment: It sounds like you would want a custom path generator for this.

Comment: I found this https://github.com/d3/d3-plugins/blob/master/hexbin/hexbin.js, but still not able to see how to transform to what I need

Comment: [Porter Duff Operators](http://www.svgopen.org/2005/papers/abstractsvgopen/index.html) would be ideal ... but not supported in most browsers. Are you seeking to have have a tick where the hexbin gradually reaches 100% or that the tick moves the segment into each quarter?

Comment: If you plan on doing what Christopher mentioned, you could possibly use a custom clip path to draw a circle which turns into a pac man like path that slowly shrinks away.